# Symfony: Doctrine-query leads to timeout

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I set up a new Symfony-Application with a new controller. When I just output static content everything works fine. But as soon as I make a MySql query (`$em->createQuery()` and `$q->getResult()`) the site is not loading anymore. After the timeout from the PHP.ini the timeout-message is displayed in the browser. The Query is simple so there should not be a problem (PhpMyAdmin needs less then 0.01 sec.).

Do you guys have any idea, what the problem could be? Database name + PW are in the parameters.yml and are correct.

Comment: Show the code pelasse

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour with `$em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->findAll()` or `->find( $id )` ?

Comment: Yes, still the same problem :(

My Code would be the following then: https://pastebin.com/s4a9Em23

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the connection (or can you insert into the db without a timeout)? Check parameters.yml again, test all the parameters, is the db behind a firewall?

Comment: Do you see an exception in dev environment? (app_dev.php). Any error in `var/log/`?